# Can EMP spectrum be approximated by black body radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation

Can the distribution of an EMP's energy by frequency be meaningfully approximated by black body radiation (at a suitable temperature)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically there is of course some best fit to a blackbody, but I seriously doubt it gives useful information.

The frequencies involved are so low ([broadband radio](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA058367.pdf), see 1-3 and 1-4) that it would correspond to a very cold object (300 kHz is 0.000005103 K), and due to different sources there appears to be many very different spectral shapes ranging from fairly pure peaks at some frequency to what looks like a 1/f distribution when skimming the literature.

As some disturbance in the EM field interacts with stuff the spectral distribution will eventually tend to approach a blackbody spectrum simply because it is the maximum entropy distribution in the photon gas domain. But this takes a lot of interaction, and absorption likely wins out long before the EMP has interacted enough.